# Put the controller json return into the phtml

Tags: magento2

I got a task to create a module and a new controller that takes orderID as a parameter and returns a JSON with information. I have created a controller and can show the JSON return, but how can I render it to the phtml?

app/code/Mymodule/OrderController/Controller/Index/OrderControl.php

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\OrderController\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class OrderControl extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

protected $orders;

protected $collectionFactory;

protected $resultFactory;

protected $jsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Order $orders,
    CollectionFactory  $collectionFactory,
    ResultFactory $resultFactory,
    JsonFactory $jsonFactory

)
{
    $this->orders=$orders;
    $this->collectionFactory=$collectionFactory;
    $this->resultFactory=$resultFactory;
    $this->jsonFactory=$jsonFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{

    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getData();
    $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $data = $result->setData($collection);

    return $data;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use it in phtml file then why not pass an Array or Collection object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your controller with below code:**

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\OrderController\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class OrderControl extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $orders;

    protected $collectionFactory;

    protected $resultFactory;

    protected $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Order $orders,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->orders=$orders;
        $this->collectionFactory=$collectionFactory;
        $this->resultFactory=$resultFactory;
        $this->jsonFactory=$jsonFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getData();
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Mymodule\OrderController\Block\Index\View')
                ->setTemplate('Mymodule_OrderController::view.phtml')
                ->setData($collection)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Create a block at** `app/code/Mymodule/OrderController/Block/Index/View.php`

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\OrderController\Block\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
 
class View extends Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**Now create a phtml file at** `app/code/Mymodule/OrderController/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml`

```
<?php

$data = $block->getData();

var_dump($data);
```